# Reverse for url generic views

Tags: django, django-urls

This subject is continuation of thinking in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212457/how-to-do-reverse-for-get-absolute-url-with-many-to-many-field). I fell back in problem of reverse in generic views. Last time I thought it's no reverse match because I used many to many, now I haven't many to *** relations in reverse but problem still in there. Since I have generic view in urls in both cases, I suggested the problem is in generic views and no view function.
 At first I used @permalink decorator in the models

```
...
@permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('categories', str(self.id))
...
@permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('pages', (), {'page_name': self.human_readable_url})
```

urls

```
url(r'^(?P<page_name>&\w*)?/?$', direct_to_template,
    {'template': 'basic.djhtml'},
    name = "pages"),
url(r'cat/\d+/$',
    direct_to_template,
    {'template': 'basic.djhtml'},
    name = "categories")
```

And got an error:

> NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'pages' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'page_name': u'page1'}' not found.

Then I tried reverse method

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('categories', args = [self.id, ])
```

And have the same error

> NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'categories' with arguments '(2,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Based on the fact that permalink not explicitly use reverse method, I think that the problem is in interaction reverse and generic view in url. Why is it happens? How to use reverse in url generic views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you have given the name `categories` to a generic view, [direct_to_template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-direct-to-template), and you are passing an argument to that view - but [direct_to_template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-direct-to-template) doesn't take that argument, only a dictionary containing extra context.

If you want to pass additional arguments to a generic view, you can - but they will only be passed on to the Template. You can [extend the view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/class-based-views/#extending-generic-views) by writing your own function, which adds the parameter into a dictionary, then calls the generic view. Something like this:

```
# views.py
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

def my_view(id):
    more_data = {'id': id}
    return direct_to_template(template = 'basic.djhtml', more_data)
```

And then in your `urls.py`, replace the `direct_to_template` with `my_view`. Since `my_view` takes an `id` argument, `reverse` will properly match it, and the argument will be passed in to the generic view, and through to the template.

Presumably somewhere in your template is a line such as, `{{ id }}`.